# Import com.google.api.client.* cannot be resolved

Tags: android, eclipse, google-places-api

I am trying to run this implementation of Google Place I downloaded from here [link](https://github.com/tuthan/Google-Place-Api-Demo/tree/master/GooglePlace).

As you can see in the following image (not in its native size but i think it works nonetheless), I am getting an error (cannot be resolved) all across my imports. You can also tell from the image that I have the Google APIs Client Library for Java in place as well as the Maven plugin since the code author mentioned having used the library in this project.

I also have added the highlighted dependency to pom.xml as suggested in another thread when using the Maven plugin. Additionally I have tried running the project against multiple sdk versions (from 2.1 as told by the author up to 3.2).

What am i missing here? This is actually the first time I have to work with external libraries so I definitely have something mixed up here.

[image]

Comment: I've finally gotten rid of errors. The post here is what did it for me[http://stackoverflow.com/a/8370318/854086](http://stackoverflow.com/a/8370318/854086)

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15714449/the-import-com-google-api-client-cannot-be-resolved-in-eclipse

Answer (score 3):

There is special versions of sdk designed to use google api.

Use "Google API 3.2" instead of "Android 3.2" in your project properties > Android > Project Build Target

Comment: I thought that would've done it, but no, using Google API 3.2 against the project did not fix the import errors.

Answer (score 0):

import the com.google.api.client.* Jar file to your project.

Comment: How would the import statement look like exactly? And will the location of the Jar file matter? I tried placing the jar file into the 'libs' folder and then adding the line _import com.google.api.client.*;_ but it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Generally the com.google.api jars will be in the below location if you successfully activate the Google API.
"C:\Users\username.m2\repository\com\google"

Please go to that location and import the all the google api related jars into your project.

I also had this issue but once i import all the jars from the above path then all the import errors have been resolved :)