# The import com.google.api.client cannot be resolved in Eclipse

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine

I am getting this error:

`The import com.google.api.client cannot be resolved`

My configuration is below:

Project Properties - Android:

[image]

Java Build Path:

[image]

I still get the error below even after restarting Eclipse.

[image]

Can anyone help? Thx :D

Comment: Eclipse sometimes is... Did you restart it?

Comment: @m0skit0 Yes, I've restarted for several times... Still not working

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You haven't added the client libraries in your project.
http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup.
You will get the google-api-java-client-1.14.1-beta.zip file at the above link.
Save those jar files in your libs folder of Android project.

Answer (score 2):

Add this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.api-client/google-api-client -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.api-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-api-client</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.oauth-client/google-oauth-client-jetty -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.oauth-client</groupId>
    <artifactId>google-oauth-client-jetty</artifactId>
    <version>1.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to add a Google API to an Android app as I was, and if you are using Eclipse, the following is very easy.

`Right-click on a project, select "Google > Add Google APIs...", select 
the Google API you need from the list of available Google APIs, 
click Finish, and it will automatically download the API client library`

From https://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/wiki/Setup